# Replay System, Ring buffer, Start Replay before Frame Buffer is reached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a replay system for a game I'm making in Unity. It stores up to the frame buffer of frames in a keyFrame array and replaces frames after it goes above the frame buffer. If you press any of the "Fire1" buttons. If there are more frames stored than the frame buffer, the replay works great, but when there're fewer frames stored than the frame buffer, it replays and stops when it gets to the empty frames nothing is moving because there aren't enough frames ([What's Happening GIF](https://gyazo.com/a84e750104f110f0ac3c8e9a7bfa88d1))

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ReplaySystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int bufferFrames = 500;
    private MyKeyFrame[] keyFrames = new MyKeyFrame[bufferFrames];
    private Rigidbody rigidBody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
            PlayBack();
        else
            Record();
    }

    private void PlayBack()
    {
        rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
        int frame = Time.frameCount % bufferFrames;
        Debug.Log("Reading frame " + frame);
        transform.position = keyFrames[frame].pos;
        transform.rotation = keyFrames[frame].rot;

    }

    private void Record()
    {
        rigidBody.isKinematic = false;
        int frame = Time.frameCount % bufferFrames;
        float time = Time.time;
        Debug.Log("Writing frame " + frame);

        keyFrames[frame] = new MyKeyFrame(time, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// A Structure for storing time, position, and rotation
/// </summary>
public struct MyKeyFrame
{
    public float frameTime;
    public Vector3 pos;
    public Quaternion rot;

    public MyKeyFrame(float time, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)
    {
        frameTime = time;
        this.pos = pos;
        this.rot = rot;
    }
}
```

How do I get the PlayBack to start from the number of keyframes stored if there are fewer frames stored than the frame buffer?

What I've already tried:
 - Counting number of keyframes stored
 - Subtracting bufferFrames from Time.frameCount then getting modulo

Answer (score 0):

My solution. Might need more tweaking.

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class ReplaySystem : MonoBehaviour {

```
private const int bufferFrames = 1000;
private MyKeyFrame[] keyFrames = new MyKeyFrame[bufferFrames];
private Rigidbody rigidBody;
private GameManager gameManager;

private bool bufferArrayFull = false;
private bool setBufferCount = false;
private int bufferCountOnClick;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    gameManager = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (gameManager.recording){
        Record();
    } else {
        Playback();
    }
}

void Playback (){
    rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
    int frame = Time.frameCount % bufferFrames;

    if (!bufferArrayFull && !setBufferCount){
        bufferCountOnClick = frame;
        setBufferCount = true;
    } else if (!bufferArrayFull && setBufferCount){
        int newFrame = frame - bufferCountOnClick;
        frame = newFrame;
    }
    Debug.Log("Playback frame " + frame + " current frameCOunt is " + Time.frameCount);
    transform.position = keyFrames[frame].position;
    transform.rotation = keyFrames[frame].rotation;
}

void Record ()
{
    rigidBody.isKinematic = false;
    float time = Time.time;
    int frame = Time.frameCount % bufferFrames;

    if (frame == bufferFrames-1 && !bufferArrayFull){
        bufferArrayFull = true;
        print ("Buffer is full");
    }

    Debug.Log("Recording frame " + frame + " current frameCOunt is " + Time.frameCount);
    keyFrames [frame] = new MyKeyFrame (time, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

}

public struct MyKeyFrame {

```
public float frameTime;
public Vector3 position;
public Quaternion rotation;

public MyKeyFrame (float aTime, Vector3 aPosition, Quaternion aRotation){
    frameTime = aTime;
    position = aPosition;
    rotation = aRotation;
}
```

}